# IMAGE_DOS_HEADER Hooking

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

I'm reading about Windows Hooking and the internals of Win32 executables (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking#Windows) and saw this block of code:

```
PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pImgDosHeaders = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)module;
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pImgNTHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((LPBYTE)pImgDosHeaders + pImgDosHeaders->e_lfanew);
PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR pImgImportDesc = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)((LPBYTE)pImgDosHeaders + pImgNTHeaders->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress);

for (IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR *iid = pImgImportDesc; iid->Name != NULL; iid++)
```

My C is a little rusty and I probably need to brush up (pointers always confuse me), but I think the way this is working is it's creating an `IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR` pointer called `iid`. `iid` points to an `IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR`, and is set equal to an object named `pImgImportDesc`. So it's looking at `pImgImportDesc`'s `Name` property, and if it's not set it'll go to the next one? So basically, it's looking for the last one?

Also any recommendations for books or videos to see more about the really low level things like this? Reading the code has me all confused.

Comment: It will go to next if it **is** set. So it goes over all of them.

Comment: The code is parsing a PE header. There is no hooking anywhere, nor is this low-level by any stretch. Asking about basic C syntax is not what Stack Overflow is meant to be used for.

Comment: Thanks for the input but how is this not low level? I mean isn't dealing with PE headers pretty low level, unless you're comparing it to assembly (I'm genuinely asking, I'm not familiar with this as much). Sorry most of my background in any type of programming is high level java/web development, I was just  trying to get the hang of dealing with stuff like this. I've seen plenty of questions here dealing with basic explanations/syntax for certain things.

Answer (score 6):

```
PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pImgDosHeaders = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)module;
```

- A process gets loaded at a particular memory address of the OS's choosing.  The `HMODULE` instance handle for the process is the same as its load address.  So this is getting a pointer to the process's `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER` struct at the beginning of the load address.

```
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pImgNTHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((LPBYTE)pImgDosHeaders + pImgDosHeaders->e_lfanew);
```

- The `e_lfanew` field is the offset to the process's `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS` struct.  This is type-casting `pImgDosHeaders` to a `BYTE*` pointer, incrementing its value by `e_lfanew` bytes, and then type-casting the result to `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS*`.

```
PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR pImgImportDesc = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)((LPBYTE)pImgDosHeaders + pImgNTHeaders->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress);
```

- Same thing as above.  `DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress` is an offset to the first `IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR` struct of the process's Imports table.  `pImgDosHeaders` is being incremented by that many bytes, and then type-casted to `IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR*`.

```
for (IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR *iid = pImgImportDesc; iid->Name != NULL; iid++)
```

- This is looping through the entire imports table.  `iid` points to the first descriptor in the table, and the loop continues through the table until it finds a descriptor without a `Name` assigned, denoting the end of the table.

Read this MSDN article for more details:

[Peering Inside the PE: A Tour of the Win32 Portable Executable File Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx)